# How to change the speed of AVPlayerViewController?

Tags: avplayerviewcontroller

Below is an factory method to setup an AVPlayerViewController. 
Everything except the speed control works fine.
In an older version of this app I was able to go from half speed to double speed by simply setting the player.rate.
Double doesn't work anymore but half speed does and I'm not sure why.
The docs say that canPlayFastForward and canPlaySlowForward need to be true however i don't see a way to set them to true.

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

    static func create(url: URL, rate: Float, time: CMTime, delegate: AVPlayerViewControllerDelegate?) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let avPlayerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerVC.delegate = delegate
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
//        playerItem.canPlayFastForward = true
//        playerItem.canPlaySlowForward =  true
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        player.rate = rate
        player.seek(to: time)
        avPlayerVC.player = player
        return avPlayerVC
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what seems to be the solution is that one cannot set the rate of the AVPlayer to 2 but one can set it to 1.99.